rCVB tumor recurrence or radiation necrosis
Can rCBV (MRI Perfusion particularly Continuous ASL and DCE) accurately distinguish between tumor recurrence and radiation necrosis or pseudoprogression in gliomas or are Cho/NAA and Cho/Cr ratios the best markers?
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/ajco.12202
The study clearly states Conventional MRI with gadolinium contrast cannot accurately distinguish between tumor recurrence and radiation necrosis or pseudoprogression because of their similar imaging appearances in gadolinium-enhanced MRI. But DWI seems to be a conventional MRI sequence too.
There are other studies e.g. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4323176/. That highlight how robust rCBV is.
